# Cookie not being handled when Page_Load() fires

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, postback, pageload

My problem is that when i press my button(which causes a postback) the cookie that is made in the `click_event` isn't being handled in a method I call in the `Page_Load`.

Here is the code:

```
//Page_Load
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
    }
    loadCookies();
}
//loadCookies
public void loadCookies()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++ )
    {
        if(Request.Cookies["FiscaleTable" + i.ToString()] != null){
           TableRow row = new TableRow();
           for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 10; i2++ )
           {
                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                cell.Text = Request.Cookies["FiscaleTable" + i.ToString()][i2.ToString()];
                row.Cells.Add(cell);
            }
            FiscaleEenhedenTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
}
//Button_Click
public void makeFiscaleEenhedenCookie(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ContentPlaceHolder Content;
    Content = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("MainContent");
    HttpCookie FiscaleEenhedenCookie = new HttpCookie("FiscaleTable" + (FiscaleEenhedenTable.Rows.Count - 1).ToString());
    FiscaleEenhedenCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 10; i2++ )
    {
        TextBox temp = (TextBox)Content.FindControl("FiscaleUnitTextBox" + (i2 + 1).ToString());
        FiscaleEenhedenCookie[i2.ToString()] = temp.Text;
    }
    Response.Cookies.Add(FiscaleEenhedenCookie);
}
//Button
<asp:Button ID="FiscaleAddButton" runat="server" CommandName="FiAdd" Text="Toevoegen" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="makeFiscaleEenhedenCookie"/>
```

As soon as I call another postback or refresh the page the cookie is being handled. I have no idea why this is happening. Any help would be helpfull.

Comment: @TusharGupta Do you mean in the if statement? Because that has nothing to do with this problem. The redirect works fine.

Comment: M sorry for my bad...I understood it differently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the expected behaviour. When button is clicked a postback is done. `Page_Load` is executed, then `makeFisicalEenhedenCookie` is executed, the page renders and it is sent to the user along with the cookie you set in the response. When another postback is done, the user sent the cookie to the server and you can handle it. It is basic flow of the asp.net page lifecycle.

In a few words: If you set a cookie in a response you can not query for the cookie until the next request.

Comment: Any idea how to fix my problem? I tried putting the 'loadCookies()' in the 'click_event' but that seems to cause problems with the rows.

Comment: There is no "problem" to fix. You need to learn more about http protocol, asp.net and how, when and for what use cookies. You are headbanging against a wall builded by yourself and there is no simple way arround it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because control events are processed after the load.
see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx for complete life-cycle.

So your code in the page load event is fired before the click event.

Comment: Page_LoadComplete still doesn't work. Remember that the cookie is not sent to the user yet.

Comment: You are right. Didn't think that through. I'll remove that part of my answer